# Inline 'add more' link not displaying in admin view

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-2.1

I have a `TabularInline` that I have added to a admin class. The inline shows OK within the admin view however the 'Add More' link does not display

I have checked JS is 100% enabled as this can be an issue according to the Django docs.

I have also checked and there are no console errors or network errors with loading any standard JS files.

I have changed max_num, min_num and extra variables within the Inline class and nothing has changed

admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

from .models import Evaluation, MV1_test

class MV1test(admin.TabularInline):
    extras=3
    max_num=5
    model = MV1_test
    verbose_name = 'MV1 Test'
    verbose_name_plural = 'MV1 Tests'

class evaluationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    save_on_top=True

    fieldsets=(
        ('General',{
            'fields':(('view_link'),('rma_number','evaluation_status','customer_name','customer_email','order_number','serial_number','firmware'),('evaluator','evaluation_date','replacement'))
            }),
            ('Visual Evaluation',{

                'fields':(
                    ('condition_heatsink',
                    'heatsink_notes'),
                    ('condition_stem',
                    'stem_notes'),
                    ('condition_oven',
                    'oven_notes'),
                    ('condition_door',
                    'door_notes'),
                    ('condition_matte_uv',
                    'matte_uv_notes'),
                    ('condition_plating',
                    'plating_notes'),
                    ('condition_bypass',
                    'bypass_notes'),
                    ('condition_coil',
                    'coil_notes')),

            }),
            ('App Evaluation',{
                'fields':(
                    ('ghost_app_connection','ghost_app_connection_notes'),
                    ('ble_connection', 'ble_connection_notes'),
                    ('firmware_update_connection','firmware_update_connection_notes')
                )
            }),
            ('Haptic Evaluation',{
                'fields':(
                    ('vape_button_haptic','vape_button_haptic_notes'),
                    ('power_button_haptic', 'power_button_haptic_notes'),
                )
            }),
            ('Battery Evaluation',{
                'fields':(
                    ('usb_charge','usb_charge_notes'),
                    ('fast_charger_charge', 'fast_charger_charge_notes'),
                    ('battery_removal','battery_removal_notes')
                )
            }),
            ('Over Door Evaluation',{
                'fields':(
                    ('door_sensor','door_sensor_notes'),
                    ('latch_spring', 'latch_spring_notes'),
                    ('oven_door','oven_door_notes'),

                )
            }),
            ('Performance',{
                'fields':(
                    ('taste_performance','taste_performance_notes'),
                    ('odor_performance', 'odor_performance_notes'),

                )
            }),
            ('ABV',{
                'fields':(
                    ('abv_pic',
                    'abv_thumbnail'),
                    ('abv_notes'),


                )
            }),
            ('Evaluation Summary',{
            'fields':(
                ('evaluation_summary'),


            )
        })
    )
    inlines=[MV1test]
    search_fields = ('serial_number', 'customer_name','customer_email','evaluator__username')#__username means look up the field from the FK
    list_filter=['evaluation_date','evaluator']
    list_display=('rma_number','serial_number','evaluator','customer_name','customer_email','replacement')

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj: # obj is not None, so this is an edit
            return ['evaluator','abv_thumbnail','evaluation_date','view_link'] # Return a list or tuple of readonly fields' names
        else: # This is an addition
            return ['abv_thumbnail','view_link']




admin.site.register(Evaluation, evaluationAdmin)
```

I expect to see an 'add more' link underneath the inline section (in the admin view) but there is no link. Also if I set extra to = 3 there should be 3 instances of the inline appearing but only ever 1 appears:

[What the inline looks like in admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdrkZ.png)

With `extra` set to 3 there should be at least 3 of the inlines showing within the view

Comment: are you superuser? This could happen if you don't have "add" permissions for the MV1_Test model (only view and edit).

Comment: Yup this is me logged in as a super user so not a permissions issue from what I can establish

Comment: When `extra=0` I see the Add Another link but when `extra=5` and `max_num=5` I only see one instance and have no link to add another